# C# / Lambda : object parameter explanation request (noob)

Tags: c#, lambda

Completly new here with a question regaridng this post : [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with a lambda expression and anonymous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738139/threadpool-queueuserworkitem-with-a-lambda-expression-and-anonymous-method)

Specific this :

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    o => test.DoWork(s1, s2)
    );
```

Can somebody please explain what the 'o' is? I can see the (in VS2008) that it is a object parameter but I basically don't understand why and how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` requires a `WaitCallback` delegate as argument.

This delegate type corresponds to `void` function of one argument of type `Object`.

So, full version of the call could be

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    new WaitCallback(delegate(object state) { test.DoWork(s1,s2); });
);
```

More concise would be

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    delegate(object state) { test.DoWork(s1,s2); };
);
```

Using C# 3.0 syntax we can write it in more short form:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (object state) => { test.DoWork(s1,s2); };
);
```

C# 3.0 lambda syntax allows to omit `state`'s type. As this argument isn't really needed, it is also abbreviated to the first letter of its type.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) of `QueueUserWorkItem`, the first parameter is a [WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) with the following definition:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(
    Object state
)
```

The definition of state is:

> ```
>  Type: System.Object
>  An object containing information to be used by the callback method.
> ```

So the first parameter of `QueueUserWorkItem` is a function which takes an object (an optional user state) and does something that returns void. In your code, o is the user state object. It is not used in this case, but it has to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Just [look it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx): The `o` is a state object you may pass to the executed method using the overloaded version of `QueueUserWorkItem`. When you don't pass one explicitly, it's `null`.

This way useful in times when no lambda expression were available.

Comment: I think what the OP is looking for is a plain english explanation of the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

`o` is a formal parameter to the lambda function. Its type is derived by the parameter type of QueueUserWorkItem.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but maybe it helps if you see what is the equivalent without using neither lambda expressions nor delegate methods (that is, doing it the .NET 1 way):

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  //...
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TheCallback));
  //...
}

void TheCallback(object o)
{
  test.DoWork(s1, s2);
}
```